# ag-Grid Internationalisation all possible properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, ag-grid

I have an Ag grid and I want to translate all possible properties of it.
I found the documentation what claims that it has all the possible properties:
[sample containing all possible values](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/#gsc.tab=0)

Now the problem is that is a little old, and there are some values what are not even in the list.
For example: notEquals.

**How could I get all the the possible keys?**

My idea is to check in the sources what Node downloads, and somehow get the keys form the ag-grid files (For instance here i found the notEquals key).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`localeTextFunc`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/#gsc.tab=0) and `console.log` the `key` and `defaultValue`. Something like this:

```
localeTextFunc: function(key, defaultValue) {
    console.log(key + ' --> ' + defaultValue)
    return defaultValue
}
```

This function gets called when it needs to display a translated value... meaning you may need to interact with the grid menus to see all the keys that will get passed through this function.